# Xamarin.Mac Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to send notification to iOS and Android devices through a Mac App made with Xamarin.Mac. I've the following code:

```
        notif_button.Activated += (sender, e) => {
            NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string>", "<hub name>");
            String pushMessage = "{ \"data\" : {\"msg\":\"" + Message + "\",\"param\":\"" + parameter + "\"}}";
            NotificationOutcome result = await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(pushMessage);
        };
```

The problem is that NotificationHubClient is not recognised. Anyone know why ? I tried to add "using Microsoft.Azure..." without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `Target Framework` of your Xamarin.Mac project to **`Xamarin.Mac Full`** vs. the default of **`Xamarin.Mac Modern`**

[image]

Once you do that, you can retarget the packages to that framework:

[image]

Now the `Microsoft.Azure.NotifactionHub` reference will show up under the package references:

[image]

Add a `using` clause of:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
```

Now you can access the `NotificationHubClient` class:

```
var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string>", "<hub name>");
```